# PostgreSQL database locks for no reason?

Tags: postgresql

I currently have a chat game which has an items database. Occasionally, the client connected to the database will get completely locked, and all queries done after that point will simply hang forever. This issue gets solved by restarting the application.

I am running the chat bot in a `node.js` app using the `pg` npm package. I am using a connection pool, which I connect to once on startup and remain connected for the life of the application.

Most of my queries are relatively simple, here is the query that modifies the inventory of users:

```
INSERT INTO items(user_id, item_id, quantity) VALUES($1, $2, $3) 
    ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT item_pk 
        DO UPDATE SET quantity = items.quantity + $3 
            RETURNING quantity;
```

When checking in pgAdmin I see that the connected client is marked as locked. I am not sure how to debug this issue or what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Consult the view `pg_locks` to find out who locks your process.

Since PostgreSQL 9.6 there is also the function `pg_blocking_pids` that can tell you which backends are holding locks blocking a certain backend.